# Login with HTTP AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I had been struggling with AsyncTask. I couldn't find the mistake. I dont understand why AsyncTask does not work although all I have is String and Boolean below here. Help please. Thank you.

The error at onPostExecute part said:

> The method did not override method from its superclass.

```
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail) && pieces[1].equals(mPassword)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    pieces[0]=arg0[0];
                    pieces[1]=arg0[1];
                }
            }
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];
            Log.i("Username", username);
            Log.i("Password", password);
            String link="http://";
            Log.i("link", link);

            // Prep HTTP for use
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(link);

            // Prep data for sending to server
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

            // Send data to server
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            String responseText = null;

            // Time to evaluate how server reacted
            try {
                // try to get server response
                responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.i("Server Response: ", responseText);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Failed to get server response, log why it failed.
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Parse Exception", e + "");
            }
            return responseText;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("exception", "error");
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        finish();
        if (success) {
            finish();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(membership.this, membership_memberonly.class);
            membership.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't your problem but you probably want to take out the code from the first `finish()` through the `startActivity()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have 2 doInBackground methods.  Only one of them should exist.

Comment: Thank you for that, I missed that but the error remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Found two doInBackground in your asyntask and protected

> String doInBackground(String... arg0)

should be

> protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0)
>
> pieces[0] = arg0[0].toString();
>   pieces[1] = arg0[1].toString();

instead of String input.

Comment: I tried that but now there is error at pieces[0]=arg0[0] and piece[1]=arg0[1] part.  
It said 
incompatible types.  
Required: java.lang.String
Found: java.lang.Object

Comment: pieces[0] = arg0[0].toString(); pieces[1] = arg0[1].toString(); and check my post.

Answer (score 0):

How can you get these override methods? Did you get any error line in this override method?

```
 @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            }
```

//here you should use the Boolean return type only, you cannot use the String. otherwise you canuse the Object instead of String like below mothod

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Remove this override method, If you couldn't able to write the proper overridden methods then do like this;

right click the method - click Source - override/Implement method then you can get the specify override methods for your method,

```
 @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                    String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                    if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                        // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                        return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

After this, method should exist then you will get an error, Also call the finish() method later in your condition.

Comment: I editted my code above here, can you take look at it again.  There was suppose one doInBackground.

Comment: Your doInBackground return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean> so, Change it to Boolean instead of String You should use like \
   
or change the AsyncTask Objects 
If you have sample login URL like you are using, then post here to try and let you know.
     @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }

Comment: But in my doInBackground's return type is String.  So, can I change something like AsnycTask<String, String, String>?

Comment: Yeah then you have to change you mentioned as well. So, Now what is your error?

Comment: The error now is on the @override at onPostExecute.  The error said: Method does not override from its superclass.  You can see my editted code above here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,I think you have copied from the outside resources for you Asynctask. So, you will cut this Asynctask class then, create a new Asynctask class like your expectation, then paste all your needed code inside the methods which are containing in the asynctask, Try this and let me know,

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. Can you repeat that.